# Extract text from array by id

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

I have this array and I want to print the questions in a text label in order. Is there a function where it can read the id of each question and sort it in order?

**This is my code:**

```
struct Question {
    let question: String
    let id: Int
    let answers: [ Answer ]
}

struct Answer {
    let id: String
    let answer: String
    let isSelected: Bool
}

struct allQuestions {

    let Questions = [

        Question(question: "The easiest way to learn is:", id: 1, answers: [
            Answer(id: "V", answer: "By viewing, reading, and observing how the others carry out certain tasks", isSelected: false),
            Answer(id: "A", answer: "By listening, discussing and doing according to verbal instructions" , isSelected: false),
            Answer(id: "K", answer: "By dping and experimenting by myself", isSelected: false)
        ]),
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Im a begginer at swift, and im currently stuck at trying to extract the question id and print the question

Comment: `Questions.sort { $0.id < $1.id }`

Comment: Struct name should start with Uppercase letter. Variable name should start with lowercase letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to sort question by id

```
let sorted =  questions.sorted(by: { $0.id < $1.id })
```

after that you can loop the array

```
for question in sorted 
{ 
    print(question.id) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need to do:

```
let orderedQuestions = questions.answers.sorted { lhs, rhs in

    return lhs.id < rhs.id
}
```

Comment: short version
`let ordered = questions.answers.sorted { $0.id < $1.id }`